# Is there any difference between these two sentences?

Tags: american-english, clauses, stative-verbs

In what form should I put nonstative verbs with "when"? E.g.,

> (1) You have to be careful when you cut a cake.
>
> (2) You have to be careful when you are cutting a cake.

Is there a difference between the two? Do they both mean the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these both essentially mean the same thing & could be used interchangeably.

I suppose there are subtle nuances if you overthink it though, so ... :)

The first sentence sounds a bit more like it refers to the entire act and ceremony of cake cutting: preparing to cut, planning where/how to cut so the pieces are equally sized, and then the actual act of cutting. It's like a rule for a student of the cake-cutting process.

The second sentence sounds more like it refers only to the specific time when you're in the act of cutting. It's like a gentle reminder that the knife is sharp, so be careful.

Another way it would be clearly different is when referring to a specific cake:

> You have to be careful when you cut **the** cake (because it's the only one!).

Vs.

> You have to be careful when you cut **a** cake (because the knife is sharp).